# Create a textfile where filename is based on the value in one or two arrays

Tags: c, text-files, fopen, naming

In a C-program I am trying to create a textfile where the file name should be based on the input to one or two char arrays in a structure.

At the moment I query the filename like this:

```
printf("Type a filename:");
scanf("%s", &filename);
strcat(&filename, ".txt");
pFile=fopen(filename,"a");
```

…but let's say my input to my char array is *John* , how could this input be used to create the filename *John.txt* ?

..or even better:  combine a name from two char arrays:

```
fgets(pIndex->name, 20, stdin);  //lets say input here is John
fgets(pIndex->country, 20, stdin);  //...and input here is England
```

to generate a filename like *JohnEngland.txt*

Thanks a lot !

-Espen

Comment: What is the problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck in how to automatically create the filename based on the input to the arrays. I would rather not ask the user to write these to values a second time. So if the input to the first array was *John*, and to the second *England* - the file created should automatically be named JohnEngland.txt

Comment: Note: you don't need address of `&filename` for `scanf()` or `strcat()`, just `filename` will do if it was declared `char filename[..]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a filename like *JohnEngland.txt* with this

```
char filename[45];
sprintf (filename, "%s%s.txt", pIndex->name, pIndex->country);
```

Comment: This is definenitly vunerable to bufferoverflows

Comment: @hetepeperfan that's true, but OP limited the string entry lengths, so I added an appropriate `fielname[]`.

Comment: No luck... Program runs, but no file is created. If I try to printf("%s%s.txt", pIndex->name, pIndex->country); it adds the newline (\n) to the output..

Comment: So did you actually get the original input with `fgets()` which keeps the `newline` entered, and not with the `scanf()` you posted?

Comment: At the moment I query the user manually using scanf, but my goal is to create the filename automatically based on the values i'we already got from the user using fgets (when getting the input to my two arrays). The newlines is added after John and after England.

Comment: @Espen, you have already told us in your post you use `fgets(pIndex->country, 20, stdin);`. That is where the `newline` is coming from and you need to remove it from each string record.

Comment: @Espen you can remove a trailing `newline` like this. `char *sptr; if (sptr=strchr(pIndex->Country,'\n')) *sptr=0;`

Comment: @WeatherVane That worked like a charm: both the answer and the solution for removing the trailing newline. Thanks for your time, it saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent overflow do

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s%s.txt", pIndex->name, pIndex->country);
```

or the MS Windows variant

```
sprintf_s(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s%s.txt", pIndex->name, pIndex->country);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function strcat and friends to concatenate multiple strings. I prefer strncat over strcat especially with user input, to prevent bufferoverflows. also don't use `"%s"` in the `scanf`, because that allows the user to insert any length of string which in turn also leads to buffer overflows.

```
#include <string.h>

const char* suffix = ".txt";
char filename[1024];
char* output = NULL;

scanf("%50s", filename); // Don't use %s because that could lead to a buffer overflow and is therfor insecure.
output = strncat(filename, suffix, 1024);
```

after the strncat filename will have the suffix appended.
check `man strcat` or your local resource for other issues involving strncat.

Comment: should consider changing:  output = strncat(filename, suffix, strlen(suffix));  _(1024 is excessive)_  (+1)